# Anonymous function in LINQ select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a code like this:

```cs
List<Item> items;
if (maxPrice)
{
    items = itemsQuery
        .Select(x => new Item()
        {
            Title = x.Key.title,
            Description = x.Key.desc,
            Stock = x.Key.stock,
            Price = x.Max(y => y.price)
        }).ToList();
}
else if (minPrice)
{
    items = itemsQuery
        .Select(x => new Item()
        {
            Title = x.Key.title,
            Description = x.Key.desc,
            Stock = x.Key.stock,
            Price = x.Min(y => y.price)
        }).ToList();
}
else
{
    items = itemsQuery
        .Select(x => new Item()
        {
            Title = x.Key.title,
            Description = x.Key.desc,
            Stock = x.Key.stock,
            Price = x.Average(y => y.price)
        }).ToList();
}
```

Is it possible to just change the `Price = x.DynamicFunc(...)` row? Because other than that it is all the same.

I tried:

```cs
Price = (x) => {
  if (maxPrice) { return x.Max(y => y.price)}
  else if (minPrice) { return x.Min(y => y.price)}
  else { return x.Average(y => y.price)}
}
```

But that gives me an error:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type "decimal" because it is not a delegate type.
```

How can I simplify this so that I don't have to repeat the whole select in 3 if branches?

Comment: and what is a type of `itemsQuery` ?

Comment: Its EF6 LINQ query, but I think that is irrelevant.

Comment: No, it is no irrelevant ... how you can do `x.title` and `x.Max(...)`  (or any other aggregate) at the same time?

Comment: There is a .GroupBy() in the query. So the type is IQueryable<IGrouping<a', b'>>.
I have updated the question with x.Key. hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: @Selvin it is `x.Key.title` though.

Comment: why not simple  `Price =  maxPrice ? x.Max(..) : minPrice ? x.Min(..) : x.Average(..)`

Comment: I would use an enum:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZqpJEF - if this will translate to SQL since you are using EF 6 - no idea

Comment: No, it will not (CS8514 An expression tree may not contain a switch expression)

Comment: Okay, the ternary operators work. Thanks @Selvin

Comment: there is a LinqKit ... and you can do [something like this](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/75e5627c23b9c6151bb2800cc25ee7a3) ... (done in LinqPad 7 with Demo database(SQLite) - working fine with sql translation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Mock Code

If I understand correctly. Your code might looks like this:

```cs
public class ItemCollectionKey
{
    public string title = "";
    public string desc = "";
    public int stock;
}
public class ItemCollection : IEnumerable<Item>
{
    public ItemCollectionKey Key = new ItemCollectionKey();
    private List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
public class Item
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = "";
    public string Description { get; set; } = "";
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public decimal price;
    public decimal Price { get => price; set => price = value; }
}
public class ItemsQuery : IEnumerable<ItemCollection>
{
    List<ItemCollection> data = new List<ItemCollection>();
    public IEnumerator<ItemCollection> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

It can be different from your source code, but I don't think it will affect the solution.

## My Solution

With the code above, we can achieve your goal with this code:

```cs
//mock data
var itemCollection_01 = new ItemCollection();
itemCollection_01.Key = new ItemCollectionKey() { title = "key1", desc = "key1_desc", stock = 100 };
itemCollection_01.Add(new Item() { Title = "item1", Description = "item1_desc", Stock = 43, Price = 12.1m });
itemCollection_01.Add(new Item() { Title = "item2", Description = "item2_desc", Stock = 57, Price = 34.2m });
var itemCollection_02 = new ItemCollection();
itemCollection_02.Key = new ItemCollectionKey() { title = "key2", desc = "key2_desc", stock = 200 };
itemCollection_02.Add(new Item() { Title = "item3", Description = "item3_desc", Stock = 93, Price = 56.3m });
itemCollection_02.Add(new Item() { Title = "item4", Description = "item4_desc", Stock = 107, Price = 78.4m });
ItemsQuery itemsQuery = new ItemsQuery();
itemsQuery.Add(itemCollection_01);
itemsQuery.Add(itemCollection_02);

//condition
bool maxPrice = false;
bool minPrice = false;

List<Item> items;

//assign function accordingly
Func<ItemCollection, decimal> getPrice;
if (maxPrice)
{
    getPrice = (ItemCollection ic) => { return ic.Max(y => y.price); };
}
else if (minPrice)
{
    getPrice = (ItemCollection ic) => { return ic.Min(y => y.price); };
}
else
{
    getPrice = (ItemCollection ic) => { return ic.Average(y => y.price); };
}

//run query
items = itemsQuery.Select(x => new Item()
{
    Title = x.Key.title,
    Description = x.Key.desc,
    Stock = x.Key.stock,
    Price = getPrice(x)
}).ToList();

//print output
System.Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", (from item in items select item.Price)));
```

## Explain

We declare `Func<ItemCollection, decimal> getPrice;` but assign it with different function for each condition. Then we run:

```cs
items = itemsQuery.Select(x => new Item()
{
    Title = x.Key.title,
    Description = x.Key.desc,
    Stock = x.Key.stock,
    Price = getPrice(x)
}).ToList();
```

`getPrice(x)` should execute the corresponding function accordingly.

### Possible output

```
when maxPrice is true:
34.2, 78.4

when minPrice is true:
12.1, 56.3

when maxPrice and minPrice are false:
23.15, 67.35
```

Comment: @popcorn why it is accepted? I'm pretty sure that this would not translate to SQL...

Comment: The way I see it, the intention behind it may be for the purpose of 'learning' since the OP (original post) only wanted to know how a Price = x.DynamicFunc(...) would look like in C#, without specifically mentioning a SQL convertible requirement. Alternatively, it could be a case of simply forgetting to include the SQL convertible requirement in the question. Nevertheless, my answer remains consistent with the original question.

Comment: Well, there is a EF tag... This doesn't work with EF

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize there was an EF tag until you mentioned it. I'll keep my current answer as it still addresses part of the question (about dynamic function in Linq). If I find another solution that works with EF, I'll append it to my current answer. Thank you for pointing that out to me. It resolves my confusion about why people are discussing SQL convertibility. Do you think you can help by editing the original post to make the question more focused on EF?

Comment: Well, OP acceptes your answer... So maybe OP did something stupid like materialisation of the query on client side and your solution  works for OP... Or use some of the solutions from comments and accept your answer as the only one... That's why I posted comment under your answer...

Comment: In that case, if the problem persists, OP can post another question. I suppose it would be better to leave it to someone who is more familiar with EF than me.